Rust - как получить все даты текущей недели?
Получил через now дату начала (beginning_of_week()) и конца текущей недели (end_of_week()). А как можно получить весь список дат текущей недели с начала и до ее конца?

Есть NaiveDate::iter_days, но для DateTime аналога не вижу, если нужен именно DateTime, то видимо придётся что-то костылировать

По идее мне days достаточно будет. Спасибо!


если нужен именно DateTime, то видимо придётся что-то костылировать

Не то, чтобы прям костылировать
let current_week = Local.beginning_of_week()
    .date_naive()
    .iter_days()
    .map(|d| Local.from_local_datetime(&d.into()).unwrap())
    .take(7);

Насчет .unwrap(), сугубо в теории, может получиться, что в некоторых таймзонах, из за перехода на зимнее/летнее время в самом начале суток, такой даты в реальности может и не существовать, либо она не однозначно определена. На практике, как мне кажется, это маловероятно либо вовсе невероятно.

«это маловероятно либо вовсе невероятно» — не стоит делать такие опасные предположения, я в своей практике уже неоднократно на подобные проблемы натыкался

@andreymal полностью согласен, поэтому и предупредил. Тот же крейт now не парится, и использует unwrap повсеместно, никого не предупреждая, даже в тех случаях, где это правда может быть опасно. А в этом конкретном, сложно себе представить такую ситуацию, что таймстамп YYYY-mm-dd 00:00:00 не существует хоть в какой-то таймзоне для произвольной даты.
